# How to use tuple to initialize case class what come from reflection

Tags: scala

I want to  use tuple to in initialize case class what come from reflection, but it doesn't work, please help me :

```
case class kof(argv1:String,argv2:String)

var kof=Class.forName("kof")
val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val classPerson = ru.typeOf[kof].typeSymbol.asClass
val cm = m.reflectClass(classPerson)
val ctor = ru.typeOf[kof].declaration(ru.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val ctorm = cm.reflectConstructor(ctor)
var sss=("22","ad")
val p = ctorm.tupled(sss)<!- here what I want to ask, please answer me as soon as possible, thank you!->
print (p)
```

Comment: I think you have to cross-post on twitter to get an emergency answer.

Answer (score 1):

Approximately:

```
scala> ctorm(sss.productIterator.toSeq: _*)
res3: Any = kof(22,ad)
```

Comment: OK. that is work.  But sss comes from a FUNC , it is not work;

Comment: var sss=("22","ad")
val p = ctorm(sss.productIterator.toSeq: _*)

Comment: that is work fine , but sss come from a FUNC , it doesn't work . for example :    var ss=new GetArgs()
    val method = ss.getClass.getMethod(logic,args.getClass)
    var sss=method.invoke(ss,args)

Comment: class GetArgs {
  def GetTwo(args: Array[String]): (String, String) ={
      print(args(0))
      return (args(0),args(1))
  }
}